# How can I set a JavaScript variable as deprecated?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, deprecated, jsdoc

I'm trying to mark a variable as deprecated. I tried:

```js
/** @deprecated */
const browser = document.getElementById("browser");
browser.innerHTML = clientInformation.appName;
```

I expected a strikethrough (that's what shows that a variable is deprecated in Visual Studio Code), but it didn't show a strikethrough (not deprecated)!

Comment: Seems to work in the TS playground: https://tsplay.dev/WPpDeW

Comment: It does work. I just tested in my vscode and it strikes both functions and variables. It might have to do with your configuration or if the size of the project is too large it might take some time for the editor to style the code completely.